# From IPLImage to Mat

Tags: opencv, image-processing, iplimage

I am well acquainted with the IPL-image format used in OpenCV 1.1. However i am using the latest 2.4 version and want to switch to the C++ interface of OpenCV. Here is the method by which i access the pixels in an image:

```
int step = img->widthStep;
int height = img->height;
int width = img->width;
unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*) img->imageData;

for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<step; j+=3)          // 3 is the number of channels.
    {
        if (data[i*step + j] > 200)      // For blue
            data[i*step + j] = 255;

        if (data[i*step + j + 1] > 200)  // For green
            data[i*step + j + 1] = 255;

        if (data[i*step + j + 2] > 200)  // For red
            data[i*step + j + 2] = 255;
    }
}
```

I need help for converting this exact code block with the Mat structure. I find several functions here and there but it will be very helpful if i get the exact conversion of the above few lines as a whole.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// Mat mat; // a bgr, CV_8UC3 mat

for (int i=0; i<mat.rows; i++)
{
    // get a new pointer per row. this replaces fumbling with widthstep, etc.
    // also a pointer to a Vec3b pixel, so no need for channel offset, either
    Vec3b *pix = mat.ptr<Vec3b>(i); 
    for (int j=0; j<mat.cols; j++)
    {
        Vec3b & p = pix[j];
        if ( p[0] > 200 ) p[0] = 255;
        if ( p[1] > 200 ) p[1] = 255;
        if ( p[2] > 200 ) p[2] = 255;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you can do the same operation on IPLImage and using the built-in constructor of Mat to convert it.

Secondly, your code seems to be overly complicated, as you're doing the same operation for all 3 dimensions. The following is tidier (in Mat notation):

```
unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*) img.data;

for (int i = 0; i < image.cols * image.rows * image.channels(); ++i) {
  if (*data > 200) *data = 255;
  ++data;
}
```

If you want the thres for the channels to be different, then:

```
unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*) img.data;
assert(image.channels() == 3);

for (int i = 0; i < image.cols * image.rows; ++i) {
  if (*data > 200) *data = 255;
  ++data;
  if (*data > 201) *data = 255;
  ++data;
  if (*data > 202) *data = 255;
  ++data;
}
```

Comment: Doing everything in IPL-image and then converting back - will this be fast enough? i dont want this process to take some extra processing time. And for that over complication thing - this is just a sample code, suppose i need to give different thresholds for red green and blue. Will your method work then ?

Comment: When you convert between Mat and IplImage, you have the option to copy the data or not. If you don't copy, the overhead is really small. Even if you copy, I doubt the overhead is significant given your whole processing takes longer than 1 sec or so. Added the case for different thresholds.

Comment: Your code does not work if the matrix has a step. That is the case e.g. for matrix headers created as a ROI of another matrix. Use iterators or row-pointer access to avoid such errors!